# Django REST framework, serializer performance degradation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple list API view which is using serializer:

```
class ListCreateDeploymentView(
    generics.ListCreateAPIView
):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    content_negotiation_class = IgnoreClientContentNegotiation

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Deployment.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def list(self, request, version):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = DeploymentListSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        data = serializer.data
        return Response(data)
```

Serializer is simple:

```
class DeploymentListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Deployment
        fields = (
            'id',
            'query',
            'config',
            'started_at',
            'finished_at',
            'status',
            'project',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'id',
            'query',
            'config',
            'started_at',
            'finished_at',
            'status',
            'project',
        )
```

Then I do a local load test with 10 users and delay 1s each execution so target rps is 10 req/s and see this picture with a clear performance degradation after few minutes

[image]
What means **If I open 10 tabs in browser with ajax request every second to this endpoint the server will get unresponsive in a minute**:

[image]

Then I used recommendations from [here](https://hakibenita.com/django-rest-framework-slow) and used read-only regular serializer:

```
class DeploymentListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # commands = CommandListSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    # clients = ClientSimpleSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    query = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    config = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    started_at = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    finished_at = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    status = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    project = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Deployment
        fields = (
            'id',
            'query',
            'config',
            'started_at',
            'finished_at',
            'status',
            'project',
        )
```

The situation became even worse:
[image]
Finally, if I remove serialization:

```
    def list(self, request, version):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        data = queryset.values(
            'id', 'query', 'config', 'started_at', 'finished_at',
            'status', 'project'
        )
        return Response(data)
```

And do same test again the performance getting much better(expected), but also stable:
[image]

The problem is I need serialization because the task is a bit more complicated and I need to return nested objects, but it`s already falling on such an easy example.

What do I wrong?

UPD: same bad picture if I use the function-based view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_deployments(request, version):
    queryset = Deployment.objects.all()
    serializer = DeploymentCreateSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    data = serializer.data
    return Response(data)
```

Comment: Did you try to test using the serializer but in the function based view so as to make the results more comparable? Possibly something different in the class based view is the reason for the degradation

Comment: Tried with 
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_deployments(request, version):
    queryset = Deployment.objects.all().prefetch_related(
        'commands',
        'commands__roadmap_phase',
        'commands__roadmap_phase__phase',
        'clients'
    )
    serializer = DeploymentCreateSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    data = serializer.data
    return Response(data)

Comment: How many worker processes are you using?  1 request = 1 worker.  When load testing its hard to separate all the factors, so I'd try benchmarking *outside* of the framework to test pure serialization speed.  Not that its fast, its not.  Here is another breakdown https://hakibenita.com/django-rest-framework-slow with some tips.  In general, your speed seems *really* bad in those examples, so whats the testing infrastructure?   I have much faster, with more db activity against a remote db, so while serializers are *fast* they arent *that* slow. Using `sqlite`?